# CSV file truncated after download

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere

The legacy J2EE application details :

- JSP + Servlets(2.4)
- Websphere Application Server 7.0
- The view is using IE frames, core javascript and so on

The user's action :

- User's search returning > 900 rows takes some time to display (NO pagination)
- User then clicks on 'Download' button which again triggers a form submit.

Following is the code snippet that is executed in the action servlet :

```
public class DownloadFileEvent extends ActionGeneric {

    java.text.SimpleDateFormat df_file = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");

    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String errormsg = null;
        StringBuffer LineBuffer = null;

        // read parameters.
        String _v = request.getParameter("view");

        // Start traitment.
        try {
            // get sessions.
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            // Create title columns.
            response.setContentType("application/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename = " + getFilename(_v));
            LineBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            //Get the string response from some business method
            //String v_wrk = getOutflow(request, _v).toString();

            LineBuffer.append(v_wrk);
            LineBuffer.append("\r\n");
            out.print(LineBuffer.toString());
            out.flush();
            // end.

        }// fin try
        catch (Exception e) {
            errormsg = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            // to do.
        }
    }// end run.

}// fin class
```

The **issue** :

- Since the 'Download' takes some time, the user moves to other screen
- When he comes back, the 'Open/Save/Save As' prompt is there already for some time. Now when user saves/opens the file but instead of 900 rows, there are less than 100 rows
- Surprisingly, if the open/save is done immediately, all the rows are downloaded
- In the catch block, I had put a log but there is no exception anywhere
- The issue is not simulated on my local machine(Windows, WAS 7) or in the SYSTEM test environment(Linux, WAS 8.5) but surfaces on ACCEPTANCE (WAS 7, Linux) and PRODUCTION(WAS 7, Linux). The ACCEPTANCE and PRODUCTION have load balancers, web server set up but NOT in systest or local

How shall I proceed ?

Comment: Where and how do you _declare_ (not instantiate) LineBuffer? Is it a servlet-class-level field? Or a local variable?

Comment: @OlafKock added more code, can you have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a high SendBufferSize in your web servers. If the client does not read while the dialog is up, this will prevent the webserver from seeing writes eventually block then timeout.

Comment: There is a load balancer and a web server involved, are you suggesting that this change is to be done on the web server level only(Apologies, I'm naive at the server things) ? Are you hinting specifically for a Websphere environment ?